# Spring WebClient - Log Uri and Method on response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have defined `WebClient`:

```java
  @Bean
  WebClient myWebClient() {
    return WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .filter(logRequest())
        .filter(logResponse())
        .build();
  }

  private ExchangeFilterFunction logRequest() {
    return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(clientRequest -> {
      log.info("MY_WEB_CLIENT | Performing {} {} request", clientRequest.method(), clientRequest.url());
      return Mono.just(clientRequest);
    });
  }

  private ExchangeFilterFunction logResponse() {
    return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(clientResponse -> {
      log.info("MY_WEB_CLIENT | Respond with {} status code", clientResponse.rawStatusCode());
      return Mono.just(clientResponse);
    });
  }
```

In `logResponse` filter method I log response `httpStatusCode`, but also I would like to add `httpMethod + uri` where a request was performed. I know I can access those data before request (using `ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor()`) but is there any way to add those data to my `logResponse` filter?

Answer (score 4):

Found the way:

```java
private static ExchangeFilterFunction log() {
    return (ClientRequest request, ExchangeFunction next) -> {
      log.info("MY_WEB_CLIENT | Performing {} {} request", request.method(), request.url());
      return next.exchange(request)
          .doOnNext((ClientResponse response) -> {
            log.info("MY_WEB_CLIENT | {} {} Respond with {} status code",request.method(), request.url(),
                response.rawStatusCode());
          });
    };
```

Comment: Any way to log request/response body?

Comment: Nice! Good job!